# Putting a polygonview on a imageview for cropping in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am making an ios application that captures a picture and enables user to crop then by their choice. I need to put a polygon view on the imageview with the help of which the user can crop the image and the cropped image will be shown on the next page.[Here i need to place the polygonview on the imageview] [enter image description here]

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What are you attempting to do?

Comment: i want to put a polygonview on the top of the imageview, so that when i set a certain region by adjusting the polygon view i get my cropped image. i am unable to understand how to put the polygonview for cropping on the imageview.

Comment: What do you mean by polygonview? A rectangle? Or should it be a more complex shape?

Comment: Yes, a rectangle that sits on the imageview. We can resize the polygonview to get our cropped image.

Comment: What's wrong with using a semi-transparent UIView?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USrMi.png my requirement is this

Comment: That's not a rectangle